# python: How to pick specific values from list

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and after trying a lot i am not able to find a solution to the below problem.

I have list (below) and want to find the index number of element provided they are continuous with exception of 1 single zero.
i.e. from below list `-7, -8, -4` should not be picked as there are more gaps of zeros between them.
But the following index number of elements should be picked

```
-6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16

2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2

21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 0

deltacount = [0, -7, 0, 0, -8, 0, 0, -4, 0, 0, 0, 
    **-6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16**, 0, 0, 
    **2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    **21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 0**]
```

Please help.

Comment: Can u more specify the condition?

Comment: I am trying to basically create a grouping i.e. if an element in list is not followed by two zeros and preceding two values is also not zero than i want to include it in the group. so from the above list there would be three groups which is marked in bold and i just want their index positions in list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    deltacount = [0,-7, 0, 0,-8, 0, 0,-4, 0,0,0,-6,0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 18, -1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 10, -10, 0, -12, 0]
zero_before_count=0
zer_after_count=0
indx=0
list1=[]
for i in deltacount:
    if i!=0:
        indx=deltacount.index(i)
        if deltacount[indx-1]==0 and deltacount[indx-2]==0:
            if deltacount[indx+1]==0 and deltacount[indx+2]==0:
                list1.append(i)
finallist=[x for x in deltacount if x not in list1 and x!=0]
print finallist
```

Try this code.

Comment: Thank You for your help. Just two more questions. Somehow -4 is missing from the group of 6, 0, -4, -29, -10, 0, -16 and also how can i get the index positions in finallist?